# SQL case when the values from different tables are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: table1 with columns id, name, and number and table2 with number, duration.
I want to output the sum of the durations if the numbers from different tables are equal.
I tried

```sql
SELECT a.name, 
       a.number, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.number == a.number THEN b.duration) 
FROM table1 a, 
     table2 b
```

but this doesn't look right.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample

Comment: Well, `JOIN` them?

Comment: (1) What is the relation between rows in tables table1 and table2?  (2) operator `==` not exists in MySQL (3) `CASE` must be finalized witj `END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query should be:

```
SELECT a.[name] AS Name
    ,a.number AS Number
    ,SUM(b.duration) AS [Total Duration]
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.number = b.number
GROUP BY a.name, a.number
```

It gives the result:

[image]

When executed using the script below:

```
create table table1 (id int, [name] varchar(50), number varchar(20))
create table table2 (number varchar(20), duration int)

insert into table1 
values 
(1, 'Joe' , '1234567890'), 
(2, 'James','2345678901'), 
(3, 'Jessy', '3456789012')
insert into table2 values 
('1234567890', 3), 
('1234567890', 3), 
('1234567890', 2), 
('2345678901', 45), 
('2345678901', 4), 
('3456789012', 5) 


SELECT a.[name] AS Name
    ,a.number AS Number
    ,SUM(b.duration) AS [Total Duration]
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.number = b.number
GROUP BY a.name, a.number

drop table table1
drop table table2
```

Answer (score 0):

> table1 with columns id, name, and number and table2 with number, duration. I want to output the sum of the durations if the numbers from different tables are equal. I tried

```sql
SELECT table1.*, SUM(table2.duration) summ
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.number = table2.number
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT a.number, sum(b.duration) FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.number = b.number
GROUP BY a.number;
```